# webpackError: process is not defined error during Gatsby js building on travis CI

Tags: graphql, travis-ci, gatsby

My `gatsby js`'s `gatsby build` works on my local machine. But it fails on `Travis CI` building process by claiming:

`WebpackError: process is not defined`

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

The full online log is here: https://travis-ci.com/Jeff-Tian/ass

It seems due to some `graphql` issues, what I should do?

---

Updated: my `gatsby-node.js` file is as follows:

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Node APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
exports.modifyBabelrc = ({ babelrc }) => ({
  ...babelrc,
  plugins: babelrc.plugins.concat(['transform-regenerator']),
})
```

Comment: hey Jeff, are you modifying webpack config in gatsby-node.js, or use any plugins that might do so? it doesnt seem to be a problem w/ graphql, webpack just couldnt pick up node's variable in travis, which is weird.

Comment: I edited the question with my `gatsby-node.js` file pasted.

Comment: so you're on gatsby v1. Gatsby v1 use a really, really old & unsupported version of webpack, so that could be where issue arises. Any chance you could convert the codebase to Gatsby v2? It's not too much work, if the site is not too complex. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/migrating-from-v1-to-v2/